# What does `console-setup/ask_detect` in a preseed config do?

Tags: preseed, setuptools

I can't find anything on `ask_detect` in any of the man pages for setupcon and almost all my search results are examples of preseed files with it set to false; nothing useful at all.

What does it actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found an answer via some [Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/apbs04.html). It disables the dialogue asking whether the installer should attempt to (sort of) automatically detect your keyboard code by making you press a few random keys.